# Security issue with chinese macro keyboard and their drivers?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, security

We got new macro rgb keyboards and knobs and I, as well as a bunch of users, keep getting popups to allow odd things, especially .msi executions and firewall exceptions. I thought this is only necessary to install once (like, for drivers) and I did refer to the instructions of "Sayo Device" but I keep seeing packages and requests like shenzhen marvo and things in actual chinese lettering.

We obviously want to allow and keep using these (already bought and people like them) but these things don't seem to ever finish setup and I am woried it might have a security problem with all this random inidentifiable stuff that it loads.

How would you deal with this, block in sonicwall and hope the keyboards keep working? Can I somehow look into what these things actually do on the PCs, anyone know logger tools or where to view that?

Comment: Keyboards that result in unknown applications being launched is never a good sign. Sonicwall might block the application from reaching out but it won't block the application from being ran on your network.

Comment: don't use those keyboards to enter login information

Answer (score 1):

**Return them or throw them away and purchase a from a trusted manufacturer.**

Using non-trusted brands in a business production environment is extremely risky. You've already identified the risk. Do you understand how the programs  being installed function? What data is being sent and received? Is it reaching out to a static IP on a specific port in China, or do these variables change?

**If you cannot answer these questions with complete certainty, you are accepting a high level of risk in your environment.**

It is highly unusual for any keyboard to request to install drivers, install executables and packages, and ask for internet access. Even premium keyboards from brands such as Logitech, Microsoft, and Razer do not request these sort of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found that there’s no need for installing any configuration software *nor* drivers for using them for some(?) of these devices.

- To use: just plug it in to a USB port of your device. (No drivers etc needed.)
- To program: *Simply visit webpage:* [https://sayodevice.com](https://sayodevice.com/) Yes really! No software download needed! It only works in the Chrome/Edge/etc browsers currently. (**WebHID** api support)

More details at https://alanjmcf.wordpress.com/2024/03/15/using-a-programmable-shortcut-keyboard-sayodevice-lichifit-etc/